# How to stop infinite loop?

Tags: python

Problem: Compute two integers based upon the user input that in the first is doubled repeatedly while second is divided by two. At each step, if second number is odd add current value of first number to itself until second number is zero.

My code doesn't seem to run completely, and I get an infinite loop what am I doing wrong? I'm using python 2.7.3

```
##
## ALGORITHM:
##     1. Get two whole numbers from user (numA and numB).
##     2. If user enters negative number for numB convert to positive.
##     3. Print numA and numB.
##     4. Check if numB is odd if True add numA to numA.& divide numB by 2 using int division.
##        Print statement showing new numA and numB values.
##     5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until numB is 0 or negative value. enter code here
##     6. Prompt user to restart or terminate? y = restart n = terminate
##
## ERROR HANDLING:
##     None
##
## OTHER COMMENTS:
##     None
##################################################################

done = False
while not done:

    numA = input("Enter first integer: ") # 1. Get two whole numbers from user (A and B)
    numB = input("Enter second integer: ") # 1. Get two whole numbers from user (A and B)
    if numB < 0:
        abs(numB) # 2. If user enters negative number for B convert to positive
    print'A = ',+ numA,'     ','B = ',+ numB
    def isodd(numB):
        return numB & 1 and True or False
    while numB & 1 == True:
        print'B is odd, add',+numA,'to product to get',+numA,\
        'A = ',+ numA,'     ','B = ',+numB,\
        'A = ',+ numA+numA,'     ','B = ',+ numB//2
    else:
            print'result is positive',\
            'Final product: ', +numA

    input = raw_input("Would you like to Start over? Y/N : ")
    if input == "N":
        done = True
```

Comment: There are a bunch of problems with your code, sadly. The biggest one is that you never change `numB` inside the loop, so you would certainly expect it to loop infinitely!

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- You don't need to write `done = False; while not done:`. Just loop infinitely (`while True`) and then use `break` to exit the loop when you're finished.
- `input` *executes* the code that the user types (think of it like what the Python shell does). You want `raw_input`, which returns a string so you need to pass it to `int`:

  ```
  numA = int(raw_input("..."))
  ```
- `abs(numB)` will compute the absolute value of `numB`, but won't do anything with it. You need to store the result of that function call in `numB`, which you do like `numB = abs(numB)`.
- The idiom `x and True or False` is not used in recent Python versions; instead, use `True if x else false`. However, returning `True` if `x == True` else `False` is the same as just returning `x`, so do that.
- You don't need to loop `while x == True`. Just loop `while x`.
- **You never change the value of `numB` inside the inner loop, so it will never terminate.**

---

Here's how I'd write it:

```
while True:
    A = int(raw_input("Enter first integer: "))
    B = int(raw_input("Enter second integer: "))
    if B < 0: B = abs(B)

    print 'A = {}, B = {}'.format(A, B)

    while B & 1:
        print 'B is odd, add {} to product to get {}'.format(A, A)
        A = # not sure what you're doing here
        B = # not sure what you're doing here
    else:
        print 'Finished: {}'.format(A)

    if raw_input("Would you like to Start over? Y/N : ").lower() == 'n':
        break
```

Comment: Thanks and I'm just starting out programming so all this is new to me. What the output is suppose to look like is the following. Welcome to Russian Peasant Multiplication!
Enter first integer: 56
Enter second integer: 37
A = 56 B = 37
B is odd, add 56 to product to get 56 A = 112 B = 18
A = 224 B = 9
B is odd, add 224 to product to get 280
A = 448
A = 896
A = 1792
B is odd, add 1792 to product to get 2072
Result is positive.
Final product: 2072
>>> ================================ RESTART 
A = 1792
B is odd, add 1792 to product to get 2072
Result is positive.
Final product: 2072

Answer (score 0):

Another problem here is that you are attempting adding to and dividing by numbers within in a print statement, so you do not change the values of the integers numA and numB at any point (that is, the integers numA and numB will remain constant throughout the program).

To change the variables numA and numB you must have:

- variable name = (some function acting on variable)

e.g.   `numA = numA + 1` to add one to numA

Comment: Thanks npupp I didn't realize I couldn't change the numA and B values inside the print statement..